# Counting Items in Python from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to search a data file, for example Yelp.json. It has businesses in it in LA, Boston, DC.

I wrote this:

```
# Python 2

# read json
with open('updated_data.json') as facts_data:
    data = json.load(facts_data)

# return every unique locality along with how often it occurs
locality = []
unique_locality = []
# Load items into lists
for item in data:
   locality.append(data["payload"]["locality"])
   if data["payload"]["locality"] not in unique_locality:
       print unique_locality.append(data["payload"]["locality"])
# Loops over unique_locality and count from locality
print "Unique Locality Count:", unique_locality, locality.count(data["payload"]["locality"])
```

But I get an answer of "Portsmouth 1", which means it is not providing all the cities and might not even be provided all the counts. My goal for this section is to search that JSON file and have it say "DC: 10 businesses, LA: 20 businesses, Boston: 2 businesses." Each payload is a grouping of info about a single business and "locality" is just the city. So I want it to find how many unique cities there are and then how many businesses in each city. So one payload could be Starbucks in la, another payload could be Starbucks in dc, another could be Chipotle in la.

Example of JSON file (JSONlite.com says its valid):

```
"payload": {
        "existence_full": 1,
        "geo_virtual": "[\"56.9459720|-2.1971226|20|within_50m|4\"]",
        "latitude": "56.945972",
        "locality": "Stonehaven",
        "_records_touched": "{\"crawl\":8,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}",
        "address": "The Lodge, Dunottar",
        "email": "dunnottarcastle@btconnect.com",
        "existence_ml": 0.5694238217658721,
        "domain_aggregate": "",
        "name": "Dunnottar Castle",
        "search_tags": ["Dunnottar Castle Aberdeenshire", "Dunotter Castle"],
        "admin_region": "Scotland",
        "existence": 1,
        "category_labels": [
            ["Landmarks", "Buildings and Structures"]
        ],
        "post_town": "Stonehaven",
        "region": "Kincardineshire",
        "review_count": "719",
        "geocode_level": "within_50m",
        "tel": "01569 762173",
        "placerank": 65,
        "longitude": "-2.197123",
        "placerank_ml": 37.27916073464469,
        "fax": "01330 860325",
        "category_ids_text_search": "",
        "website": "http://www.dunnottarcastle.co.uk",
        "status": "1",
        "geocode_confidence": "20",
        "postcode": "AB39 2TL",
        "category_ids": [108],
        "country": "gb",
        "_geocode_quality": "4",
        "uuid": "3867aaf3-12ab-434f-b12b-5d627b3359c3"
    },
    "payload": {
        "existence_full": 1,
        "geo_virtual": "[\"56.237480|-5.073578|20|within_50m|4\"]",
        "latitude": "56.237480",
        "locality": "Inveraray",
        "_records_touched": "{\"crawl\":11,\"lssi\":0,\"polygon_centroid\":0,\"geocoder\":0,\"user_submission\":0,\"tdc\":0,\"gov\":0}",
        "address": "Cherry Park",
        "email": "enquiries@inveraray-castle.com",
        "longitude": "-5.073578",
        "domain_aggregate": "",
        "name": "Inveraray Castle",
        "admin_region": "Scotland",
        "search_tags": ["Inveraray Castle Tea Room", "Inverary Castle"],
        "existence": 1,
        "category_labels": [
            ["Social", "Food and Dining", "Restaurants"]
        ],
        "region": "Argyll",
        "review_count": "532",
        "geocode_level": "within_50m",
        "tel": "01499 302203",
        "placerank": 67,
        "post_town": "Inveraray",
        "placerank_ml": 41.19978087352266,
        "fax": "01499 302421",
        "category_ids_text_search": "",
        "website": "http://www.inveraray-castle.com",
        "status": "1",
        "geocode_confidence": "20",
        "postcode": "PA32 8XE",
        "category_ids": [347],
        "country": "gb",
        "_geocode_quality": "4",
        "existence_ml": 0.7914881102847783,
        "uuid": "8278ab80-2cd1-4dbd-9685-0d0036b681eb"
    },
```

Comment: Can you share your 'updated_data.json' with few records?

Comment: Just added a snippet of the JSON file

Comment: The sample json in your question doesn't have the outermost enclosing `{`, and `}` characters. If they really are there, then when you `json.load()` it into Python it will become a dictionary with only _one_ `"payload"` key in it because dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. `print(data)` and see what's in it.

Comment: @martineau you're right. it only printed the last content entry of payload.

Comment: In that case your input isn't meaningful even though it technically it appears to be syntactically valid. If you update your question and show us _exactly_ the format of the data, it might be possible to modify it programmatically on-the-fly so that it can be processed the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

If your "json" semantics is something like

```
{"payload":{ CONTENT_A }, "payload":{ CONTENT_B }, ..., "payload":{ CONTENT_LAST }}
```

it is a valid json **string**, but after you json.loads the string, it will be evaluated as

```
{"payload":{ CONTENT_LAST }}
```

And that is why you end up with one city and one business count.

You can verify this behaviour on this online json parser http://json.parser.online.fr/ by checking JS eval field.

In this case, one way to preprocess your json string is to get rid of the dummy "payload" key and wrap the content dictionary directly in a list. You will have a json string in the following format.

```
{[{CONTENT_A}, {CONTENT_B} ..., {CONTENT_LAST} ]}
```

Assume your json string is now a list of payload dictionary, and you have json.loads(json_str) to *data*.

As you iterate through json payload, build a lookup table along the way.
This will handle duplicated city for you automatically since business in the same city will be hashed to the same list.

```
city_business_map = {}
for payload in data:
    city = payload['locality']
    business = payload['name']
    if city not in city_business_map:
        city_business_map[city] = []
    city_business_map[city].append(business)
```

Then later on, you can easily present the solution by

```
for city, business_list in city_business_map.items():
     print city, len(business_list)
```

If you want to count the unique business in each city, initialize the value to set instead of list.

If this is an overkill, instead of initialize to list or set, just associate a counter with each key.

Comment: @Aaron Your json string does not seem to be valid though... what is the semantic for the entire json string? Are these payloads wrapped in a dictionary?

Comment: There is a { before all  the payloads and } at the end.

Comment: @Aaron then you should preprocess this json string as I described in the answer.

Comment: Point of clarification: Is your "business_list" suppose to be "business"? You never declare business_list.

Comment: How to you get rid of the dummy "payload" key and wrap the content dictionary directly in a list? I tried creating a list and writing a for loop to add each item to the list but it did not work for me. (Payload is the overarching group that holds all the information about a business - the business name, business address, business email...)

Comment: You really don't describe how to "preprocess" the string in your answer.

Comment: @Aaron `city_business_map` is in a dictionary, the key is the city, and the value is a **list** of business, which I call a business_list, it's just a value holder in the for..in loop. As for preprocessing, the most simple and naive way is to just do pure string processing, simply use regular expression to (1) remove the '"payload":' occurrences and then (2) insert a [ after first { and insert a ] before the last}.